# Show that $\mathcal Y \subset C([0,T], X_1)$ continuously.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

I am reading *Navier-Stokes Equations* by Roger Temam and there is some step in a proof I don't understand. Let me recall the settings.

Let $X, X_0, X_1$ three Banach spaces with $X_0, X_1$ reflexive, such that
$$X_0 \subset X \subset X_1$$
continuously and  the inclusion $X_0 \subset X$ is compact. Let $T > 0$ a fixed finite number and $\alpha_0, \alpha_1 > 1$. Let us define
$$\mathcal Y = \left\{v \in L^{\alpha_0}(0,T; X_0)~\big|~ v' \in L^{\alpha_1}(0,T;X_1)\right\}$$
endowed with the norm
$$\|v\|_{\mathcal Y} = \|v\|_{L^{\alpha_0}(0,T; X_0)} + \|v'\|_{L^{\alpha_1}(0,T;X_1)}$$
which makes it a Banach space.

I am reading the proof that $\mathcal Y \subset L^{\alpha_0}(0,T; X)$ is compact. At some point in the proof, the author uses the fact that $\mathcal Y \subset C([0,T], X_1)$ continuously and I do not understand why. I know the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $u, v \in L^1(0,T; X)$, for $X$ a Banach space, such that
> $$\int_0^T u(t) \phi'(t)dt =-\int_0^T v(t) \phi(t)dt,$$
> for all $\phi \in C^\infty_0([0,T])$. Then $u$ is a.e. equal to a continuous function from $[0, T] $ into $X$.

Therefore the inclusion
$$\mathcal Y \subset C([0,T], X_1)$$
is trivial by the lemma. However, I do not see how could I show that it is continuous. Indeed, to this end, we should be able to show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that, for all $u \in \mathcal Y$,
$$\|v\|_{C([0,T], X_1)} \le C \|v\|_{\mathcal Y},$$
which means
$$\|v(t)\|_{X_1} \le C(\|v\|_{L^{\alpha_0}(0,T; X_0)} + \|v'\|_{L^{\alpha_1}(0,T;X_1)}), \quad \forall t \in [0,T].$$
I tried many things but I did not find anything.. Any help ?

Comment: The answer to your question is the same as in the special case $X_0=X=X_1=\mathbb R$.

Comment: And how do we show that in that case ?

Comment: Write $u(t) = u(s) + \int_s^t u'$, take absolute norms everywhere, integrate wrt$s$. For sure there are  posts here about this as well.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin–Lions_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma

Comment: Is it possible to have a complete answer?